# Default Function/Value for JavaScript Class

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to set something of a default/fallback function for a JavaScript class?

```
var a = new function() {

  this.b = function() {
    return "B";
  }

  return "A";
}
```

In this example, I'd want to see `B` when executing `alert(a.b())`, and `A` for `alert(a)` alone.

Comment: Why are you using `a = new function(){}`? Do you know what it is doing? It's more or less equivalent to `a = {}`.

Comment: @FelixKling I assume he wants to create an object literal but with logic. new function() {} is basically that. I presume the real example has actual logic in the constructor

Comment: @Raynos: Yeah, that could be....

Comment: Indeed. Thanks for the help! <3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var a = new function() {    
  this.toString = function() { return "Four Loko comes in 8 different flavors."; };
  this.valueOf = function() { return "Four Loko comes in 8 different flavors."; };
  this.b = function() { return "Added! :3"; };
}
alert(a);
alert(a.b());
```

If you overwrite the `toString` method of an object you can get it to return whatever you want.

Although you may be trying to return literal values from a constructor. You can only return objects from a constructor.

You may also want to overwrite `.valueOf`

Comment: Sorry, I missed the `new` keyword. The whole setup seems unnecessary confusing to me. An object literal is just as good.

Answer (score 1):

Your question and your sample code are a little vague but this might be what you're looking for:

```
function A() {
    this.b = function () {
        return "Added! :3";
    }
}

var a = new A();
alert( a.b() );
```

which would be better if you do it this way:

```
function A() {}

A.prototype.b = function () {
    return "Added! :3";
}
```